# TypeError: categoriesService.createCatergry is not a function

Tags: node.js

I have this problem in this part of my code
the curse that I study with there is no problem with the teacher I also search a lot
on this code is the controller of the API that I try to build

```
exports.create = (req, res, next) => {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            next(err)
        }
        else {
            const path = req.file != undefined ? req.file.path.replace(/\\/g, '/') : "";

            var model = {
                categoryName: req.body.categoryName,
                categoryDescription: req.body.categoryDescription,
                categoryImage: path != "" ? '/' + path : ''
            }

            categoriesService.createCatergry(model, (error, results) => {
                if (error) {
                    return next(error)
                }
                else {
                    return res.status(200).send({
                        message: 'Success',
                        data: results
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

that the code in service file

```
async function createCategory(parmas, callback) {
    if (!parmas.categoryName) {
        return callback({
            massage: 'Category name is required'
        },
            ""
        );
    }
    const model = new category(parmas);
    model.save().then((response) => {
        return callback(null, response);
    }).catch((error) => {
        return callback(error);
    })
}
```

when I click on it say remove unsend function

Answer (score 0):

Please check if it's not misspelled `createCatergry`

Comment: there is no misspelled that the code in the service file

Comment: i have upload the code in the post

Comment: @IbrahimMahmoud if your code is latest one, there is typo in function names.
You defined `createCategory` but you are invoking `categoriesService.createCatergry`.  `createCategory` and `createCatergry` are not equal